# Query cyrillic data with Sqlite3 and Android Studio

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, encoding, sqlite

I'm trying to filter some records from a sqlite3 database, but i am getting incorrect results. 
For input, i have a cyrillic string. In the database all strings are encoded into UTF8, so they look like something like this "%D0%A5%D0%90%D0%93...".
I encoded the input string into UTF8 and query the database. The code in Android studio is something like this:

```
   String where = (Upper(name) like '%" + URLEncoder.encode(lookFor.toUpperCase(), "UTF-8") + "%');

   DB.query("Clients",
             new String[]{"name", "saldo", "db_id", "_id"},
             where,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null);
```

The query return results, but there are many invalid records between them. Do i address the problem right or miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not UTF-8 encoding, it is URL encoding.

The percent sign is used as a pattern character by LIKE, so that is the most unsuitable encoding that could have been chosen.

The best idea would be do not encode the strings; SQLite and Android handle plain Unicode strings just fine.
But if you must keep the database contents this way, you could tell the LIKE to use a different pattern character with the [ESCAPE clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like).